# Adding Textarea to the right next of the previous textarea in html/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I'm developing one dashboard for my team. The power point presentation of the dashboard is looks like [image]

so I plan to go with text-area tag, but I don't know how to create the multiple textarea like "Last week Accomplishment" is one text area when i try to create another text area for "Goals" It is displaying under the "last week" text area. I want it into the right side.
Then last left corner of the ppt consist table. I got confusion after seeing this tables. I'm very new to html and css. Suggest me get the correct answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code so others may help you. This might be useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, a little CSS styling should help. Just set:

```
.yourtextboxSelector {
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
}
```

Also set width for your text-areas, so that they would fit in one line, for example, 50% or less. Would be better if you provide some of your html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `float:right` to the css code of the first textarea.

Answer (score 0):

`.column{float:left; width:50%;}`
Use this "column" class for your text-area tag this will align "Goals" text-area next to the "Last week Accomplishment".